# index.html page not loading in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

in **`app.js`**

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl : appUrl + '/index.html',
    controller : 'HomePageController'
});
```

in **`controller.js`**

```
angular.module('PoliticalOrg').controller('HomePageController',function(   $scope ) {

$scope.Login= function () {
alert("s");
 }
 });
```

in **`index.html`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en" ng-app="PoliticalOrg">
      <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Organization</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,  maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta content="" name="description">
    <meta content="" name="author">

       <link href="assets/plugins/pace/pace-theme-flash.css" rel="stylesheet"   type="text/css" media="screen">
     <!-- BEGIN CORE CSS FRAMEWORK -->
        <link href="assets/plugins/boostrapv3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <link href="assets/plugins/boostrapv3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <link href="assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- END CORE CSS FRAMEWORK -->
    <script src="libs/vendor/angularJS/angular.min.js"></script>
      <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 
    <script src="js/login/config.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login/Controllers.js"></script>
    <script type="js/login/services.js"></script>
    <script type="js/globalmethods/login.js"></script>
     <!-- BEGIN CSS TEMPLATE -->
     <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/css/custom-icon-set.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- END CSS TEMPLATE -->

     <script src="js/app.js"></script>
     <script src="js/Controllers.js"></script>
 
        <script src="js/registration/config.js"></script>
        <script src="js/registration/Controllers.js"></script>
   
        <script src="js/login/config.js"></script>
         <script src="js/login/Controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/login/services.js"></script>
   
       <script src="js/candidate/config.js"></script>
       <script src="js/candidate/Controllers.js"></script>
       <script src="js/candidate/services.js"></script>
   
       <script src="js/submemberrequests/config.js"></script>
        <script src="js/submemberrequests/Controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/submemberrequests/services.js"></script>
   
        <script src="js/messages/config.js"></script>
       <script src="js/messages/Controllers.js"></script>
       <script src="js/messages/services.js"></script>
   
        <script src="js/users/config.js"></script>
         <script src="js/users/Controllers.js"></script>
         <script src="js/users/services.js"></script>
   
          <script src="js/admin/config.js"></script>
         <script src="js/admin/Controllers.js"></script>
         <script src="js/admin/services.js"></script>
   
         <script src="js/users/services.js"></script>
        <script src="js/globalmethods/map.js"></script>
        <script src="js/globalmethods/login.js"></script>
    </head>
     <!-- END HEAD -->

      <!-- BEGIN BODY -->
      <body class="boxed-layout  breakpoint-1024 pace-done grey"><div class="pace  pace-inactive"><div class="pace-progress" data-progress-text="100%" data-progress="99" style="width: 100%;">
       <div class="pace-progress-inner"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="pace-activity"></div></div>
    <!-- BEGIN HEADER -->
      <div class="container">
     <div class="header navbar navbar-inverse "> 
      <!-- BEGIN TOP NAVIGATION BAR -->
       <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="header-seperation" style="display: none; height: 61px;"> 
            <ul class="nav pull-left notifcation-center" id="main-menu-toggle-wrapper" style="display:none"> 
             <li class="dropdown"> <a id="main-menu-toggle" href="#main-menu" class=""> <div class="iconset top-menu-toggle-white"></div> </a> </li>   
            </ul>
          <!-- BEGIN LOGO --> 
          <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="" data-src="assets/img/logo.png" data-src-retina="assets/img/logo2x.png" width="106" height="21"></a>
          <!-- END LOGO --> 
          <ul class="nav pull-right notifcation-center"> 
            <li class="dropdown" id="header_task_bar"> <a href="index.html" class="dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle=""> <div class="iconset top-home"></div> </a> </li>
            <li class="dropdown" id="header_inbox_bar"> <a href="email.html" class="dropdown-toggle"> <div class="iconset top-messages"></div>  <span class="badge animated bounceIn" id="msgs-badge">2</span> </a></li>
            <li class="dropdown" id="portrait-chat-toggler" style="display:none"> <a href="#sidr" class="chat-menu-toggle"> <div class="iconset top-chat-white "></div> </a> </li>        
          </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- END RESPONSIVE MENU TOGGLER --> 
          <div class="header-quick-nav"> 
          <!-- BEGIN TOP NAVIGATION MENU -->
          
         <!-- END TOP NAVIGATION MENU -->
         <!-- BEGIN CHAT TOGGLER -->
          <div class="pull-right"> 
            <div class="chat-toggler"> 
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="my-task-list" data-placement="bottom" data-content="" data-toggle="dropdown" data-original-title="">
                        <div class="user-details"> 
                            <div class="username">
                                
                                 <span class="bold">Login</span>         
                            </div>      
                        </div> 
                        <div class="iconset top-down-arrow"></div>
                    </a> 
                    <div id="notification-list" style="display:none">
                        <div style="width:300px">
                           
              <div class="grid-body no-border">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                
                <p>Enter your username and password to login</p>
                <br>
                <div class="row form-row">
                  <div class="input-append col-md-10 col-sm-10 primary">
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="someone@example.com">
                    <span class="add-on"><span class="arrow"></span><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i> </span> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row form-row">
                  <div class="input-append col-md-10 col-sm-10 primary">
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="your password">
                    <span class="add-on"><span class="arrow"></span><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> </span> </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-actions">
                <div class="pull-right">
                  <button type="button" ng-click="Login()" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons-md"> login</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-white btn-cons-md">Clear</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
                            </div>    
                    </div>
                </div>
             
          </div>
           <!-- END CHAT TOGGLER -->
          </div> 
          <!-- END TOP NAVIGATION MENU --> 

      </div>
      <!-- END TOP NAVIGATION BAR --> 
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END HEADER -->
<!-- BEGIN CONTAINER -->
<div class="page-container row-fluid">
  <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR -->
  
  <a href="#" class="scrollup to-edge">Scroll</a>
  <!-- END SIDEBAR --> 
  <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTAINER-->
  <div class="page-content condensed" data-height="679"> 
    <!-- BEGIN SAMPLE PORTLET CONFIGURATION MODAL FORM-->
    <div id="portlet-config" class="modal hide">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"></button>
        <h3>Widget Settings</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"> Widget settings form goes here </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="content">  
  <div class="page-title"> 
   <h3>Home Page</h3>  
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- BEGIN CHAT --> 

<!-- END CHAT -->
 </div>
<!-- END CONTAINER --> 
<!-- BEGIN CORE JS FRAMEWORK--> 
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="assets/plugins/boostrapv3/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="assets/plugins/breakpoints.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-unveil/jquery.unveil.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-block-ui/jqueryblockui.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- END CORE JS FRAMEWORK --> 
<!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL JS -->  
<script src="assets/plugins/pace/pace.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-numberAnimate/jquery.animateNumbers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->  

<!-- BEGIN CORE TEMPLATE JS --> 
<script src="assets/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/chat.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<!-- END CORE TEMPLATE JS --> 

</div><div style="left: -1000px; overflow: scroll; position: absolute; top: -1000px; border: none; box-sizing: content-box; height: 200px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 200px;"><div style="border: none; box-sizing: content-box; height: 200px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 200px;"></div></div></body></html>
```

I mentioned `app.js` and `controller.js` in `index.html`. Here's the problem I am facing. When I click on the login button in index.html `ng-click="Login()"` function defined in `HomePageController` the Login function is not called.

Comment: can I see your `index.html`?

Comment: could you add some more of your index.html code?

Comment: how are you creating the module? I mean that `angular.module('PoliticalOrg')` is just calling it. You should have some code including the dependencies' array like `angular.module('PoliticalOrg', [])` to create it. Have you got any error in console?

Comment: i did not get any errors in console.

Comment: maybe try  changing the type  `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Comment: why are you using routeProvider here??

Comment: when app launching time load the index.html page

Comment: not working @Mike0

Comment: updated the index.html code please look at once @pietro909

Comment: It turns out that you never call the controller in you HTML: I provided an answer.

Comment: does the `HomePageController` included in the html file?

Comment: yes,included in app.js

Comment: sorry, totally missed it.

Comment: no i meant like did you include the `HomePageController` script file in the html file?

Comment: yes,included in html file @Mike0

Comment: just put `alert("s");` outside the login function, just to check if the controller loaded correctly

Comment: alert("s"); placed in out side not called @Mike0

Comment: How can i call HomePageController Login function @Mike0

Answer (score 0):

This happened because the controller is not loaded correctly, you were trying to load the controller form the index.html page at the same time you included your scripts on index.html page.

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl : appUrl + '/index.html',
    controller : 'HomePageController'
});
```

so what you should do is breakdown your views using `ui-view`.
put the folowing in `home.html` file

```
<!-- BEGIN CHAT TOGGLER -->
          <div class="pull-right"> 
            <div class="chat-toggler">  
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="my-task-list" data-placement="bottom" data-content="" data-toggle="dropdown" data-original-title="">
                        <div class="user-details"> 
                            <div class="username">

                                 <span class="bold">Login</span>                                    
                            </div>                      
                        </div> 
                        <div class="iconset top-down-arrow"></div>
                    </a>    
                    <div id="notification-list" style="display:none">
                        <div style="width:300px">

              <div class="grid-body no-border">
              <div class="row-fluid">

                <p>Enter your username and password to login</p>
                <br>
                <div class="row form-row">
                  <div class="input-append col-md-10 col-sm-10 primary">
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="someone@example.com">
                    <span class="add-on"><span class="arrow"></span><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i> </span> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row form-row">
                  <div class="input-append col-md-10 col-sm-10 primary">
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="your password">
                    <span class="add-on"><span class="arrow"></span><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> </span> </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-actions">
                <div class="pull-right">
                  <button type="button" ng-click="Login()" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons-md"> login</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-white btn-cons-md">Clear</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
                            </div>              
                    </div>
                </div>

          </div>
           <!-- END CHAT TOGGLER -->
```

and add `ui-view` in the index.html instead of the above code. then change the route like this

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl : appUrl + '/home.html',
    controller : 'HomePageController'
})
```

**i.e you should initialize the index.html from the file not from the route**

Follow this [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) documentation.